# Mirroring dates in Python

Tags: python, datetime

Say we have a system that runs continuously, and that we make some changes to it on a particular date `start_date`.

We would like to compare the effects of the changes between:

- The time window of **full days** between `start_date` and today's date (shown in yellow below)
- The **equivalent** time window (same days of the week) of full days that took place **right before** `start_date` (shown in blue below)

For example, say I started my experiments on **March 25** (in red), and that today is **March 29** (green), I would like to obtain the **four** dates that define
`time_window_before` (the two dates in yellow) and `time_window_after`( the two dates in blue).

[image]

The idea is to compare the results of the experiment started on `start_date` **before and after** the experiment started, on the **longest possible** number of days on a time window that is symmetric (in terms of days of the week) to the date the experiment started.

In other words, given `start_date` and today's date, how can I find the pairs of dates that define `time_window_before` `time_window_after` ( as `datetime` objects)?

## Update

Since I was asked what happens if `start_date` and today's date don't fall on the same week, below is one such example:

[image]

Comment: I think I understand what you want if experiment_start_date and today fall on the same week, but it is not at all clear what you want if they fall on different weeks.

Comment: @HeikkiToivonen I have updated the OP. The assumption is that the system has been running "forever". The goal is to maximize the size of the window on which we compare while respecting the symmetry around (1) days of the week and (2) the experiment date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should do it:

```
def get_symmetric_time_window_fwd(ref_date, end_date):
  da1 = ref_date+timedelta(1)
  da2 = end_date-timedelta(1)

  if da2.weekday() >= ref_date.weekday():
    db2 = da2 - timedelta( 7 * (1+int((end_date - ref_date).days/7)))
  else:
    db2 = da2 - timedelta( 7 * (int((end_date - ref_date).days/7)))

  db1 = db2-(da2-da1)

  return da1, da2, db1, db2
```

**Test 1:**

```
In: get_symmetric_time_window(date(2014, 3, 18), date(2014, 3, 29))
Out: 
(datetime.date(2014, 3, 19),
 datetime.date(2014, 3, 28),
 datetime.date(2014, 3, 5),
 datetime.date(2014, 3, 14))
```

**Test 2:**

```
In: get_symmetric_time_window(date(2014, 3, 25), date(2014, 3, 29))
Out: 
(datetime.date(2014, 3, 26),
 datetime.date(2014, 3, 28),
 datetime.date(2014, 3, 19),
 datetime.date(2014, 3, 21))
```

**Test 3:**

```
In: get_symmetric_time_window(date(2014, 7, 17), date(2014, 7, 23))
Out: 
(datetime.date(2014, 7, 18),
 datetime.date(2014, 7, 22),
 datetime.date(2014, 7, 11),
 datetime.date(2014, 7, 15))
```

Answer (score 2):

This works at least in your two samples, would this be good enough?:

```
experiment_start_date = datetime.date(2014,3,18)
now=datetime.date(2014,3,29)

day_after1 = experiment_start_date+datetime.timedelta(1)
day_after2 = now-datetime.timedelta(1)
day_before2 = experiment_start_date-datetime.timedelta(day_after2.weekday()-experiment_start_date.weekday()+1)
day_before1 = day_before2-(day_after2-day_after1)
```

Comment: Thanks, what is `db2`, `da1` and `da2`? Are they the acronyms for the corresponding `day_before` and `day_after`?

Comment: Oops, I copied code and forgot to change those to the more readable names, fixing...

Comment: Hmm, it worked well until I tried the following dates: `experiment_start_date='2014-7-17'` and `now = '2014-7-23'`. For those two dates, it returns `day_before1 = '2014-7-14` and `day_before2 = '2014-7-18'`, but it should have returned:  `day_before_1 = '2014-7-11'` and `day_before_2 = '2014-7-16'`

Answer (score 2):

Python's `datetime` library has all the methods you need to add and subtract the dates:

```
from datetime import date, timedelta

def get_time_window_after(experiment_start_date, experiment_end_date):
  # Add 1 day to start and subtract 1 day from end
  print "After Start: %s" %(experiment_start_date + timedelta(days = 1))
  print "After End: %s" %(experiment_end_date - timedelta(days = 1))

def get_time_window_before(experiment_start_date, experiment_end_date):
  # Find the total length of the experiment
  delta = experiment_end_date - experiment_start_date
  # Determine how many weeks it covers (add 1 because same week would be 0)
  delta_magnitude = 1 + (delta.days / 7)

  # Subtract 7 days per week that the experiment covered, also add/subtract 1 day
  print "Before Start: %s" %(experiment_start_date - timedelta(days = 7 * delta_magnitude) + timedelta(days = 1))
  print "Before End: %s" %(experiment_end_date - timedelta(days = 7 * delta_magnitude) - timedelta(days = 1))
```

Here's the examples I ran the code with to make sure it works:

```
print "\nResults for March 25 2014 to March 29 2014"
get_time_window_after(date(2014, 3, 25), date(2014, 3, 29))
get_time_window_before(date(2014, 3, 25), date(2014, 3, 29))

print "\nResults for March 18 2014 to March 29 2014"
get_time_window_after(date(2014, 3, 18), date(2014, 3, 29))
get_time_window_before(date(2014, 3, 18), date(2014, 3, 29))

print "\nResults for March 18 2014 to April 04 2014"
get_time_window_after(date(2014, 3, 18), date(2014, 4, 4))
get_time_window_before(date(2014, 3, 18), date(2014, 4, 4))
```

Note: If you make these functions return values and set variables, you could use the `time_window_after` as input into `get_time_window_before()` function and forego the duplicated `timedelta(days = 1)` logic.

Comment: `get_time_window_before` doesn't work. E.g. `get_time_window_before(date(2014,3,25), date(2014,3,29))` returns `2014-03-15` to `2014-03-18` but it should have been `2014-03-19` to `2014-03-21`